# Unable to write cache

Tags: symfony, permissions, webserver

Hi all im working with Symfony2. I dont have problems with the project in my computer but when i upload the files in the web server, fails for cache permissions.

I set the permissions in my computer with this steps:

```
$ rm -rf app/cache/*
$ rm -rf app/logs/*
$ APACHEUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX app/cache app/logs
```

As sugest [The Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup).
So, upload the app/cache and app/logs (empty) folders to my webserver.
Whe in try access to the web project, Symfony says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Could
>   not create cache directory
>   "/home/coleman/public_html/apps/app/cache/prod/annotations"

I check the folder with Filezilla, and the permissions are 666 (read and write for all).
I dont know that are wrong.

Any ideas ?.

Answer (score 5):

See this link:

**[Configuration and Setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup)**

It's pretty common issue. You need to configure permissions though `ACL`...

Comment: thank for reply, i update the thread with more info. Your solution dont work.

Comment: try removing `cache` directory altogether and creating a new one. Then, `chown user:user app/cache`, while replacing `user` with current user. Also, be sure **not** to run that as `root`. Then, apply `ACL` permission change. Needless to say, run those commands from application's root (not from `/app`), since as I recall you won't receive any error anyways....

Comment: Configuring ACL is what did it for me. ( Ubuntu Desktop )

Comment: I have edited /var/apache2/envvars and set `APACHE_RUN_USER` and `APACHE_RUN_GROUP` to my root user and now works. Thanks

Comment: As described by @JovanPerovic http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup. It works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Is your project name "apps" ? If not, seems like you put your web folder content at root without modify the relative paths in your app.php

Comment: `/home/coleman/public_html/apps` is the document root of the subdomain that contains the project.